# How to know from what microsoft package/update a .dll file comes from?

Tags: powershell, updates, .net-framework, packages, assembly

There are plenty of specific missing X.dll requests here.
I would like to know how to get where does a .dll file *should* come from, especially a microsoft .dll.

I have a missing assembly error on my program, and I am not sure about downloading it from a random .dll site (I didn't find it anyways).

Here is the [class I need to use](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.updateservices.administration.updatescope(v=vs.85).aspx) 
Missing file : Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.dll 
**How to know which update comes with this file ?** I didn't find any info on this.
Where can I securely download missing .dll's ?

I am using .NET framework 4.6.1 and Powershell 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Missing file: Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.dll

You need to install the [WSUS 3.0 SP2 Administration Console](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd939875%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

> You need to explicitly install the WSUS Admin Console on the
>   development machine (to reference it), and you must install the WSUS
>   Admin Console on any machine that is intended to use your project.
>
> The DLL is not licensed for redistribution, but it must physically
>   exist on the local machine. The only way to get it (legally) is to
>   install the WSUS Admin Console. The console requires the .NET
>   Framework v2.0 and an authenticated connection to the WSUS server
>   (i.e. the console machine and the WSUS server must have a domain trust
>   relationship).

Source [Windows Update Services Administration DLL](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/d6d089a0-6945-4f4e-88ec-7cb315f49336/windows-update-services-administration-dll?forum=winserverwsus)

This file `Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.dll` is also installed as part of Windows Server Update Services Service Pack 1:

> <kbd>[image]</kbd>

Source [Description of Windows Server Update Services Service Pack 1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/919004)

Comment: Thx for answering. I was about to edit my post pointing to this software. Do I have to setup a whole WSUS network to monitor ? What if I have to check servers on different domain ? Thanks

Comment: Done. Now my question is still pending, how do you determine the provenance of one .dll or another ?

Comment: Don't know about provenance. Just make sure you only download them from the correct vendor site not some random site.